# Simple Sinatra Pagination

Tags: ruby, api, sinatra

I am working with an API and I am trying to develop a simple pagination from scratch in Sinatra

This is my Sinatra route - it performs the API Call and returns 25 matters with the limit: 25 parameter and stores the resulting array in @matter -

```
 get '/matters' do
  @matter = client.matters.list(limit: 25)
  slim :matters
 end
```

My plan to get additional matters is

```
get '/next_matters' do
  @matter = client.matters.next_page
  slim :matters
end
```

Which supposedly returns the next 25 matters
This is my slim code at the bottom of the list of matters:

```
a href= "/next_matters" Next
```

This does not work - It returns nothing - I am sure this is because when I call next_matters is does not remember the state from client.matters.list(limit: 25).

Do I need a helper method for this?

When I try:

```
  get '/matters' do
   @matter = client.matters.list(limit: 25)
   @matter2 = client.matters.next_page
  slim :matters
 end
```

I can list 50 matters - some how I need to pass the fact that I have called list previously

How do I do this?

Comment: Doesn't the api provide something like skip?

Comment: You probably want to use sessions to store your objects between requests

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a part time Ruby/Rails job.. Do you have any to offer ?

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by passing in an offset to the database as part of the query.

i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM matters LIMIT 25;
```

Then on requesting the next page, you would do:

```
SELECT * FROM matters LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25;
```

Therefore, the `next_page` method needs to accept at least 1 parameter; an offset.

Pseudo code:

```
def next_page(offset)
  # first page offset would be 0
  # second page offset would be 25
  # ...
  limit(25).offset(offset)
end
```

Comment: This code would be great if I had access to the Database but I am accessing the Info through an API client is a method that accesses the API